# How to keep unique validation Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel

In my CreateUserRequest for email it has the validation rule of unique, and it's the same for my EditUserRequest, but It keeps saying that the address is already registered. How do I exclude the email address of the user I am updating from the uniqueness in the rules? Otherwise I have to register a new email address every time the user is updated.

EditUserRequest:

```
namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Http\Requests\Request;

class EditUserRequest extends Request
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'unique'=>'That email address is already registered',
            'regex'=>'Password must contain at least 1 letter and 1 number'
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name'=>'required|min:2|max:50',
            'email'=>'required|email|unique:users,email|max:50'
            //'password'=>'min:8|regex:/[a-zA-Z][0-9]/' NOT IN USE WHILE IN DE
        ];
    }
}
```

CreateUserRequest:

```
namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Http\Requests\Request;

class CreateUserRequest extends Request
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'unique'=>'That email address is already registered',
            'regex'=>'Password must contain at least 1 letter and 1 number'
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name'=>'required|min:2|max:50',
            'email'=>'required|email|unique:users,email|max:50',
            'password'=>'required'
            //'password'=>'required|min:8|regex:/[a-zA-Z][0-9]/' NOT IN USE WHILE IN DE
        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your EditUserRequest and add ID of the current record to be ignored.

Take a look at the official docs:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#rule-unique
in the paragraph: Forcing A Unique Rule To Ignore A Given ID

Something like:

```
'email'=>'required|email|unique:users,email,'. $user->id .'|max:50'
```

Comment: You can use Request::input('id') instead of $user->id if you don't have dependency injection.

Comment: You can also use `request()->id`.

Comment: It says that $user is undefined though. How do I give rules() access to the $user?

Comment: Using Request::input('id') or request()->id doesn't do anything either - get the same error, that the email address is already registered.

Comment: try to use fixed ID instead of $user->id ... some real record like 123 and if this is ok (for edit the record with id 123) then you have some other problem.

Comment: If I use a fixed ID it works - I just can't get the ID to the request for some reason. Yeah using Laravel.

Comment: what is your route for the edit action? somehow you transfer the id to know what record you are editing, so use the same way

Comment: It's part of a resource: 

`Route::group(['middleware'=>'admin'], function() {
    Route::resource('admin/users', 'AdminUsersController');
    Route::resource('admin/posts', 'AdminPostsController');
});`

The URI is admin/users/{users}/edit and the name is admin.users.edit

Comment: Try to dd(Request::all()); is not clear why is "{users}" but if is then with Request::input('users) you should get the ID of the record.

Comment: `array:7 [▼
  "_method" => "PATCH"
  "_token" => "47z8EWfouWLeqYk2UkuEA5I9pY2GSTQ2CsaDSObw"
  "name" => "Alastair Appleby"
  "email" => "ali@alijared.com"
  "role_id" => "1"
  "is_active" => "1"
  "password" => ""
]` is the output of dd(Request::all()); which is basically all the information that was sent via the form

Answer (score 0):

All that was necessary was adding `$user = User::find($this->users);` and then just appending `$user->id;` as suggested. Was just missing finding the user in the first place.